# How to get the right position with Sortable.js, acts_as_list and Stimulus for nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, sortablejs, acts-as-list, stimulusjs

I'm trying to implement the "Drag and Drop Sortable Lists" (https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-drag-and-drop-sortable) with nested_attributes.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the wrong `:position`. It jumps from 2 to 5 to 7, even when there should be only three positions in total.

**I believe the problem is that hidden input tags are being counted as well. If this is the main problem, any way around this?**

```
// config/routes.rb

  resources :recipes, except: :index do
    resources :steps do
      resource :step_position, only: :update
    end
  end
```

```
// app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb

<div data-controller="sortable" data-sortable-url="/recipes/:recipe_id/steps/:id/step_position">
  <%= f.fields_for :steps, @recipe.steps.order(position: :asc) do |step| %>
    <div data-id="<%= step.object.id %>">
      <%= step.text_area :description %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```
// app/javascript/controllers/sortable_controller.js

import { Controller } from "stimulus";
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
import { Sortable } from "sortablejs";

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.sortable = Sortable.create(this.element, {
      onEnd: this.end.bind(this),
    });
  }

  end(event) {
    let id = event.item.dataset.id;
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("position", event.newIndex + 1);
    Rails.ajax({
      url: this.data.get("url").replace(":id", id),
      type: "PATCH",
      data: data,
    });
  }
}
```

```
// app/controllers/step_positions_controller.rb

class StepPositionsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @step = Step.find(params[:step_id])
    authorize @step.recipe

    @step.insert_at(params[:position].to_i)

    head :ok
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am stuck at the same spot and my sort order is doing the same thing. Jumping up to 7 when I only have 3 total. If so what did you end up doing?

Comment: @spacerobot, yeah I did! Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that hidden input tags were being counted as well.

I solved it by adding `<%= f.hidden_field :id %>`

```
<!-- app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb -->

<div data-controller="sortable" data-sortable-url="/recipes/:recipe_id/steps/:id/step_position">
  <%= f.fields_for :steps, @recipe.steps.order(position: :asc), include_id: false do |step| %>
    <%= render "step_fields", f: step %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```
<!-- app/views/recipes/_step_fields.html.erb -->

<%= content_tag :div, class: "nested-fields", data: { new_record: f.object.new_record?, id: f.object.id } do %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>

  <small><%= link_to "Delete", "#", data: { action: "click->new-fields#removeField" } %></small>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind posting your step controller?

Comment: @spacerobot Stayed the same as above! Didn't have to touch it.

Comment: @MirhaMasala Thanks, in my case adding <%= f.hidden_field :id %> solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly take a look at the parameters being passed to the server. Do these look ok? If not, then the javascript might be to blame.

Secondly, `insert_at` isn't the best tool for the job in this case. If you want to explicitly set the position explicitly without interference from the callbacks etc... I usually use `where(:id => id).update_all(:position => the_position)` on each element in the list (provided you know you have all of them in your params.

The best solution is to have the javascript send you the item being moved and the position in the list that you want it to be, then just set the position column to that value and `acts_as_list` will shuffle things out of the way for you. The only downside to this is concurrent updates from other users. Your list will get out of sync if this is the case.